# Azure: deploy static html app when pushed with GIT

Tags: git, azure, deployment, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service

I configured Azure to deploy an app from External Git source, using an App Service. The problem is that I have to press the Sync button every time I need a new deploy after a push.

Is there a possibility to trigger a deploy after push for static html files(not ASP.NET app) on Azure App Service? The repository is on a private BitBucket server(not the same as a private repository from the official website).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this repo:

https://github.com/beberlei/symfony-azure-edition

I have used to do my Symfony deployment into Azure Web App, the key part is the .deployment file. Everytime that you do a push to the remote azure, it will search for the instructions in .deployment file and execute it.

In the example project, .deployment file calls a bash script that perform the rest of the required tasks to deploy the Symfony project.